# Python Selenium crashes when element not found

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Python Selenium to open a URL from a list and find a certain element. like so...

```
driver.get('http://www.example.com.com/')
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("my-field")
```

If the element exists then everything works fine, but if the element can't be found then the script crashes with en error...

```
Unable to locate element:
```

Is this correct behaviour and is there a way to deal with this instead of crashing out?

Comment: You might want to add a [wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html) to really confirm that the element does not exist.

Answer (score 9):

It is correct behavior.

You can catch the exception, like you can any exception:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
...
try:
    driver.get('http://www.example.com.com/')
    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("my-field")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("couldn't find the element")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. From the docs:

> ...
>   With this strategy, the first element with the id attribute value
>   matching the location will be returned. If no element has a matching
>   id attribute, a NoSuchElementException will be raised.

And the exception could be catched of course(like mentioned in another answer).

You can find docs here:
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html#locating-by-id

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the element does not appear at once, for this case we need to use explicit wait. You can just check if the element exist, without crashes.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)

def is_element_exist(text):
    try:
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, text)))
    except TimeoutException:
        return False
```

Solution without `try/ except`:

```
def is_element_exist(text):
    elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, text)))
    return None if elements else False
```

How explicit wait works you can read [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Imports:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```